# Filtering information in two attribute tables using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, spatial-join, filter

I'm an amateur in QGIS so please forgive me for not using the correct definitions. I have a polygon map (shapefile) with the neighbourhoods of my city. Each one of this neighbourhoods has it's own identifier, name and other information columns in the attribute table.

In the other side, I have other layers that are just X and Y coordinates from, for example, schools in this city. I need to find the neighborhoods of these coordinates but I've found no way to do it. I can't filter both information (neighborhood and coordinates) since they're different layers.

Of course it can be done manually, but I think there's a way to do it in a quick manner.

I've searched GIS SE but I haven't found anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find join by location in Processing Toolbox
[image: Find join by location in Processing Toolbox]

Then select intersects and contains and run

[image]

You will get neighborhoods with intersected X,Y points
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem right:
Vector -> Data management -> join attributes by location: target points, join neighborhoods.

OR

the plugin point sampling tool

(both layers must have the same CRS)